# How to store some text in a ms word file in a specific format using java or php?

Tags: java, docx

I am looking to write some code using java or php which writes or store some data in a ms word file in a specific format. The format should be like the document is in A4 portrait mode divided into four equal blocks. All the blocks have a logo in the background and a text is written aligned to the center which is same in two blocks always.

I am sorry if this was not the right way to ask or if I have done something wrong. I am very new to programming and this is the first time I am asking a question on stackoverflow.

I looked for it on this website but couldn't find something similar.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions like this should not be asked on SO. Please show us what you have tried and why it's not working (including the relevant piece of code), and we can help you to fix your problem.

Comment: I didn't have much idea as I already mentioned I am new here. Now I don't know what to do with the question as it is not allowing me to delete this post and I don't want to waste time of anyone else reading it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try: [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) which allows you to create, modify and display word documents using Java. Here's a great tutorial that can help:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_quick_guide

Comment: Thank you this look like much of a help. I will try this and next time post with more resources if I need help.